# rules for unary operators in bison

Tags: parsing, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, bison

I am trying to write bison expression for arithmetic operations, and for unary operators. the rules for unary operator should be

--6  is not accepted, but -(-6) accepted

4--5 and 4+-5  are not accepted, but 4-(-5) accepted

4*-5 and 4/-5  are not accepted, but 4*(-5) accepted

3- is not accepted

-3*4 is accepted

the rules are

```
line
    : assign '\n'            {      
                    long temp=eval($1); 
                LIST_EXPR[count-1].value=temp;
                LIST_EXPR[count-1].flag=1;
                printf("   %ld\n", LIST_EXPR[count-1].value);
            }
    ;

assign
: VAR '=' expr           { $$ = make_binop(EQUAL, BINOP_EXPR, make_var($1), $3); add_to_list_expr($3,count); count++;}
| expr          {add_to_list_expr($1,count); count++;}
;

expr
: expr '+' term          { $$ = make_binop(PLUS,BINOP_EXPR, $1, $3);}
| expr '-' term          { $$ = make_binop(MINUS,BINOP_EXPR, $1, $3);}
| term
;

term
: term '*' factor        { $$ = make_binop(TIME,BINOP_EXPR, $1, $3);}
| term '/' factor        { $$ = make_binop(DIV,BINOP_EXPR, $1, $3); }
| term '%' factor        { $$ = make_binop(MOD,BINOP_EXPR, $1, $3); }
| factor
| pre
;

pre: 
  '-' factor         {$$=make_binop(UMINUS,BINOP_EXPR, $2, NULL);}
| '+' factor         {$$=make_binop(UPLUS,BINOP_EXPR, $2, NULL);}
;

factor
: '(' expr ')'           { $$ = $2; }
| CONST          { $$ = make_const($1); }
| VAR                    { $$ = make_var($1); }
| '#' factor         {$$=make_binop(LINE_REF,BINOP_EXPR, $2, NULL);}
;
```

the problem is when the unary come in the right side it is accepted, for example 3--4 it is accepted, while it should not be accepted. this problem occur just with + and - operation.

Does anyone know how to solve it

Comment: `3--4` is valid. It is 3 binary-minus unary-minus 4. No problem here to solve. `pre` is usually called `primary`, and what you have called `term` is really `factor`, and so on. Have a look at the grammar of any standard programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar has:

```
expr: expr '-' term
term: pre
pre : '-' factor
```

So 3--4 must be accepted; `-4` is reduced to `pre` and then `term`, and then `3--4` has become `expr - term`, which reduces to `expr`.

Similarly `-3*4` will reduce `-3` to `pre` and then `term`, after which it can be used to reduce `-3*4` to `term`, by using `term: term '*' factor`.

It is unclear to me why you want `3--4` to be invalid, while you are willing to accept `-3-4` as well as `-3*4`. `3--4` is not, imho, any more or less confusing than those other two, and it does not create any ambiguities.

But if that's what you want, you could achieve it by distinguishing the `term`s which can be unary expressions, and those that cannot (untested):

```
expr : expr '+' rterm
     | expr '-' rterm
     | term
rterm: term '*' factor
     | term '/' factor
     | term '%' factor
     | factor
term : rterm | pre
pre  : '-' factor | '+' factor
factor: VAR | CONST | '#' factor | '(' expr ')'
```

Comment: Thank you so much that work perfectly. This some kind of compiler for arithmetic operation for some language. And the assumption is this kind operation not accepted.

Comment: @Hukh Why not? It's accepted in every programming language I have ever used, and every branch of mathematics I have ever studied. I'm sure you're wrong about this.